# ofdm sysetm with usrp implemntation

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am trying to build an ofdm flow graph with usrp, as shown below

[Flowgraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR1tq.png)

The flowgraph works fine without any errors. However, there is no received signal at the receiver end as shown in [results(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu6XU.png) and [results(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uATQx.png).
It seems that the USRP does not get data/signal from the OFDM Trasnmitter, and the signal shown at Rx spectrum is just noise.
Any recommendation to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. your sampling rate is too low. The USRPs you're using probably aren't running at the rate - look for the warnings at the beginning of your flow graph execution about other sampling rates being used
2. The gain is too low, probably, for over-the-air transmission.
3. The analog bandwidth settings make no sense. Since this seems to be a network-connected USRP: only very few of these have adjustable frontend bandwidths, anyway, but using a frontend bandwidth much larger than your sampling rate makes no sense.
4. Most importantly: **This is communications, with a random channel, noise, interferers and device imperfections.** It's very normal for packets to get lost.

Comment: I increased the sample rate to 1.5 M, and changed the BW to 2MHz. It still gives the same errors. Also, It gives zero as an output. I tried similar flow graph with using channel model instead of usrp, and I got an output. Moreover, there are no warnings before the ones shown on the figure. "-- Opening a USRP2/N-Series device... -- Current recv frame size: 1472 bytes -- Current send frame size: 1472 bytes -- Opening a USRP2/N-Series device... -- Current recv frame size: 1472 bytes -- Current send frame size: 1472 bytes"

Comment: again, a bandwidth larger than your sampling rate makes no sense. Again, a channel and a channel model are only similar if you parameterize the model to reflect realities.